# How can I composite two alpha channels using a "max" operation?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Suppose I draw two overlapping translucent shapes in a canvas:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)";
context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
context.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "??????";
context.fillRect(150, 150, 200, 200);
```

After this, I want the RGB values of each pixel to be (0, 0, 0) and for the alpha to be the *maximum* of the alpha channels of the two shapes. In other words, what I should get is that if a pixel is in either of the two squares it has alpha 0.25, otherwise it's blank. So the entire drawn region should be a uniform color.

I can't find any blending operation that does this. If I use things like "lighter" or "darker", [I get a darker region where the two squares overlap](https://jsfiddle.net/7y4s8Lhn/).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably HERE in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: None of the compositing formulas use the max operation on the alpha channel. The alpha channel is not treated the same way as the color channels. If you wanted the entire area to have the same alpha, there are various methods that could be used, but getting the maximum of the destination and source alpha channels may require per-pixel operations.

Comment: There are several ways you can do this. If you have CORS headers (or same domain) use `ctx.getImageData` `ctx.putImageData` and set the pixels manually (via JavaScript) or use SVG filter via the `ctx.filter` property (however this may (???) taint the canvas), or use WebGL and create a fragment shader to mix the images.